# Diazo: not style overlay windows in Plone

Tags: plone, diazo, xdv

I am upgrading to Plone 4.2 (from 4.0.1) and moving my theme product from XDV to Diazo.

A bug has presented where when i submit a form from an overlay to a custom page template, the resulting page is 'plain'. By 'plain' I mean the only visible content is the main content area, there is no plone nav, logo, none of the style sheets are present etc. There is an 'info' message passed to this page and that does get rendered at the top of the page (nothing is styled with any plone or theme styles though). It's like the target page is rendered outside of the Plone space altogether.

I have tried adding  to my rules.xml and adding the corresponding ajax_load = python: request.form.get('ajax_load') to the parameters in the theming control panel 'advanced settings' section. The overlay is still themed however, and the form target page is still 'plain' (I wont say 'unthemed' as even an unthemed Plone page still has the basic logo, nav etc).

I also tried add a  and sticking an item with this id in my overlay template - the overlay still gets themed.

I am using the theme rule

Not sure why the overlays remain themed and if this is part of the problem? Also not sure why the form target page template is rendered 'plain'.

If i submit the same form normally (not from an overlay) the target page renders properly themed...

Any tips to debug this would be great thanks.

Am using Plone 4.2.0.1 and plone.app.theming 1.1a2, my theme is file system based.

---

**Edit**: OK some of my overlay forms are working properly. The difference seems to be where the form action is:

form tal:attributes="action request/URL" - works OK

form tal:attributes="action string:${context/absolute_url}/@@view" - gives me the 'plain' page at first render when called from an overlay form (as discussed above is fine when called from the same form not in an overlay)

Note that the 'plain' page html goes like this (note no base Plone or Theme head inclusions):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><base href="http://localhost:8080/Plone/sectionfoo/sectionbar/mypage" /><!--[if lt IE7]></base><![endif]--></head>
<body class="template-view portaltype-myCustomType site-Plone section-sectionfoo icons-on havePortlets haveLeftPortlets haveRightPortlets" dir="ltr">
<h1 class="documentFirstHeading">Why is this page plain?</h1>
...
```

I also tried completely uninstalling my theme product - i still see the same behaviour from these particular overlay forms in vanilla plone...

Comment: Can you show us (at least some of) the code from your template? Is it failing to load the resources, or just not referencing them at all? Is the URL of the page different when it's submitted from the overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a JavaScript .prepOverlay() call to set up the ajax overlay, then it will automatically append the ajax_load flag as part of the query string used via AJAX to get the code that's displayed in the overlay.

See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquerytools/1.5#ajax for an explanation of what ajax_load does. In brief, it causes the server to strip everything but the content area off. The purpose is to avoid loading unnecessary page parts into an overlay, which is already displayed inside a page.

If the form you load is posting to itself (a very common Zope/Plone practice), then the ajax_load parameter may be in the form action URL. So, you get only the content area returned.

So, you'll need to do some work in your custom form template to make sure you strip "ajax_load" off the query string of the URL before you set the form action. Also, strip any "ajax_load" hidden input out of the form.

Comment: Thanks Steve, definitely no ajax_load in the form action or hidden fields.

Comment: Works fine when posting to itself... just blows up when posting to a different target eg
`form tal:attributes="action request/URL"` - works OK
`form tal:attributes="action string:${context/absolute_url}/@@view"` generates the plain page after submit.

I dont see the ajax_load param in self.request.URL, is there somewhere else i should be inspecting to find it? I use pdb...

Note: these overlay forms used to work fine on Plone 4.0.1, this bug started once we upgraded to Plone 4.2.

Cheers

Comment: OK I have found 'ajax_load' in self.request.keys(), and then it is still set when the form is submitted from the overlay. Seems like a workaround but should i try and remove this when i parse the form? Any tips on how to do this? I couldnt easily remove self.request['ajax_load'] using pdb as self.request identifies as type 'instance' and I can't see a method to remove it via dir(self.request)?

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is the hidden input mentioned at the end of the answer. Can you inspect the overlay-displayed form and see if it has a hidden input with name "ajax-load"?
If that's it, it's probably something we should fix in the overlay support. It probably should not be adding that input on any form that isn't set up for ajax posting.

Comment: You're right thx Steve. I did say earlier there was no 'ajax_load' hidden form field in the overlay, but now i see there actually is. I have my theme turned off now so that may have been obscuring me seeing it earlier... so yes it is definitely there in the overlay form. Any tips on how i can remove it - jquery?